# Python open browser and run javascript function

Tags: javascript, python

I have a question about python and javascript. I like to create a file who comminicate with javascript webpage.

First i will create a Python file who will open a local webpage. This example localhost/test.html
This page is a themplate page. The code is

```
<html><head><title>An example application</title></head>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
}
</script>
    <body>
    <h1 class="content">This is my sample application</h1>
    Put the content here...
    <hr>
    <a href="/exit">Quit</a>
    </body></html>
```

Whene everything is loaded and displayed the python file will activate the javascript function "myFunction()"

How do I do that? I am running Debian and have installed Python and Chromium.

Comment: I deleted the webbrowser-control tag, ActiveX is not a realistic outside of Windows.

Comment: can you give more background on this question? Why do you need browseer and not V8 binding?

Comment: Allright: I have a raspberry pi with a NFc reader connection. I have a browser. Chromium in this case. The pythonscript communicate with the NFc reader. I this case it use the python-pyscard library. When i use my NFc card the python script need to access the browser. It will execute a javascipt what i need to use for this webpage

Answer (score 5):

You need a library to allow interaction between the browser and the program.

Options include [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) and [Ghost](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/).

Comment: I am using raspberry pi. I really like Selenium because you can run chrome as kiosk mode. But there is no way i could install the chrome web browser. I can use java, but it is to heavy I think to run on a raspberry pi

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [webbrowser module](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html) ? It can be used to display your webpage.
It can not call your js function, but perhaps that one can be triggered from the ready() event in the html?

Comment: I is easy to run a webbrowser in debian put i need tot communicate with hardware. That's way the javascript function is really important

Comment: ok. I though the problem was showing a website and triggering a function, after the python was done doing something.

Answer (score 0):

You could open the website from python using [webbroser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) module with an url parameter containing your javascript code.

in your example

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('http://localhost/test.html' + '?script=myFunction();')
```

Then you can read the url paramater in your javascript and execute it via [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var url = new URL(window.location.href);
        var script = url.searchParams.get("script");
        console.log(script);
        eval(script)
    }    
</script>
```

Please be aware, that this is only suitable for testing or developing purposes and must not be used in production since using eval like this is [dangerous](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval_needlessly!).