# save document.cookie output in a file

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

[skillshare-downloader](https://github.com/kallqvist/skillshare-downloader) says:

> grab your cookie by typing:
>
> ```
> document.cookie
> ```

Then it says:

> Copy-paste cookie from developer console (without " if present) into example script.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> from downloader import Downloader
>
> cookie = """
> ADD YOUR COOKIE HERE
> """
> ```

It adds an extra step.

Is there any way we can save `document.cookie` output to a file so that we can just read the cookie from the file instead of going to the console and type `document.cookie` and copy-paste the output?

I checked [How to write console.log to a file instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54654946/how-to-write-console-log-to-a-file-instead). I also checked [Python open browser and run javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798301/python-open-browser-and-run-javascript-function). It suggests using Selenium or [webbroser module](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/webbrowser.html). However, I am not sure how to approach this problem.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using chrome:

1. Install selenium by running in a terminal `pip install selenium`
2. Install a chromedriver via a manager (It allows you to control chrome) by running in a terminal `pip install webdriver-manager`
3. Create a file example.py and paste this inside

```js
   

#import the selenium webdriver and the chromedriver
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from time import sleep

#trying to stop skillshare from detecting we a are a bot
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

#create the instance of chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)

#get command used to open an url
driver.get('https://www.skillshare.com/')


#login part
#press on sign in
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.button.alt-white-ghost.transparent.initialized").click()

#change email here
driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys("testmail@mail.com")

#change password here
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("fakepassword")

#wait a second
sleep(1)

#click on sign in
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Sign In']/parent::button").click()

#wait 3 seconds for the login
sleep(3)

#execute_script is used to execute the command in the browser console, using return here to store it in a variable
cookie = driver.execute_script('return document.cookie')

#python way of creating a file on the given path and write the cookie inside it
f = open("D:\cookie.txt", "w")
f.write(cookie)
f.close()

#closing the chrome instance
driver.close()
```

open a terminal and type python example.py and it will run the script

Comment: Do I have to login to https://www.skillshare.com/ each time or do we have a way to maintain the login state when using selenium?

Comment: hey, im not sure how long that cookie lasts after the login on that site. You have 2 options: 1. I can add the login steps and generate the cookie after or 2. launch the chrome with your user profile (same as a normal chrome, where you are already logged in). Both are easy to do.

Comment: thank you very much. I actually change few lines to use it in Linux with Firefox. I will be glad if you kindly add the login steps and generate the cookie after.

Comment: I've added the login steps, unfortunately the site has a CAPTCHA. hopefully that part with  options will hide it from the site.

Comment: there is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67517044/load-firefox-user-profile-with-particular-settings-in-user-agent-switcher-and-sp) related to this. Will be glad if you can kindly help.