# Load Firefox user profile with particular settings in User-Agent Switcher and Spoof Timezone

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am using Linux Mint 20. I am using [User-Agent Switcher and Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-string-switcher/) and [Spoof Timezone](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/spoof-timezone/) with firefox. I want to load the current firefox user profile and use Chrome 99.0.7113.93 (Windows) user agent using selenium. In addition to that, when right click on *Spoof Timezone*, there is an option *Update timezone from IP*, I also want to click that before going through rest of the process.

Currently I am following [save document.cookie output in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67368249/1) and came up to:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(
    executable_path=GeckoDriverManager(cache_valid_range=1).install())

driver.get('https://www.skillshare.com/')

cookie = driver.execute_script('return document.cookie')

f = open("/home/blueray/Desktop/cookie.txt", "w")
f.write(cookie)
f.close()

driver.close()
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cant exactly click on the on the extensions with selenium, since they are not part of the page DOM.

For **User-Agent Switcher and Manager** you can just inject the user agent without using the extension

For **Spoof Timezone**, You can access the about:addons, click on the extension, preferences, check the automatically update timezone based on my IP address and click save. Cant do it with selenium since that part is under a shadowroot that doesnt display these settings. Hopefully when the selenium launches you will have the setting already saved, after you've done this step manually.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile


options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()


# Define and set the user agent to Chrome 99;
# The User-Agent Switcher and Manager extension has no config page that we can access as an url and click on it with selenium;
# Therefore we can injecting the user agent instead
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.7113.93 Safari/537.36"
options.set_preference("general.useragent.override", user_agent)

# load the firefox profile 
# to get this: open in firefox the url about:profiles and its the Profile: default-release => Root Directory
firefox_profile = FirefoxProfile('/home/art/.mozilla/firefox/kd5i4tgp.default-release')

options.profile= firefox_profile

firefox_profile.add_extension("/home/art/.mozilla/firefox/kd5i4tgp.default-release/extensions/{55f61747-c3d3-4425-97f9-dfc19a0be23c}.xpi") # for spoof timezone

#download from here https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.29.1 linux64.tar.gz, I've put mine in Documents
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options,executable_path="/home/art/Documents/geckodriver")


driver.get('https://www.skillshare.com/')

cookie = driver.execute_script('return document.cookie')

f = open("/home/blueray/Desktop/cookie.txt", "w")
f.write(cookie)
f.close()

driver.close()
```

Comment: Glad i could help :)