# [Python]: Opening a Chrome tab and running some Java Script there

Tags: python

I want to open a new browser tab where I would like to run JavaScript code. Something like:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open_new_tab('http://www.google.com')
```

but with a second argument which would be the JavaScript code.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798301/python-open-browser-and-run-javascript-function

Comment: You can use Selenium to achieve this

Comment: Installed Selenium (with pip). How can I achieve this @kodwx?

Comment: @Jermartyno Again. Duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794087/running-javascript-in-selenium-using-python

Comment: @Vusal I wanted to open a new tab in Firefox which I've installed myself, not in an environment for testing purposes. Is it still possible to do in a normal Firefox browser/ the one I use everyday?